# IE7 Object Expected on External JS functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

If i try and call a function from an external JS file it returns object expected in IE7 only. If i take the function out of the external JS file and declare it in the head (within document ready) it runs without problem.

Completely at the end of my tether and at a loss

Things i have tried

1. Changed the type attribute on the javascript tags
2. Tried added http:// to the google hosted jquery links instead of just //ajax
3. Tried calling function after document ready
4. Tried moving all js to the bottom of the file
5. Created a seperate JS file just for IE and tried to call a function from it
6. Same as above with an empty function
7. Tried using defer on the script tag
8. Tried removing script type and adding language="javascript"
9. Ran all js through JS lint
10. Searched the first three pages of google for the answer using variations of keywords
11. Checked the JS file is loading correctly

Comment: Code needed. I assume you mean "Object expected" - it sounds like you are trying to call a function before that function is available.

Comment: Check your console for errors.If it shows up only in IE 7, it may be a bug.I can't say more without knowing the exact code.